# Embedded C++: Help optimizing some conditionals?

Tags: c++, arduino, embedded

I've got a real-time embedded system I'm building with Arduino (using PlatformIO actually). I've got it working fine as a proof of concept, but now I'm trying to optimize a bit.

I have two variables describing the measurement units the system is operating in:

1. Gearbox Pitch, which is an enum that can be `tpi`, `in_per_rev`, or `mm`
2. Leadscrew Pitch, which is an enum that can be `tpi` or `mm`

Remember dimensional analysis from high school chemistry class? This code basically does that. At a conceptual level, it's just a really long unit conversion, which works differently based on those two variables. And I'm trying to do it as close to real time as possible.

Right now my code works like this:

```
// Split math into two parts
float numberPart1;
float finalNumber;

// Calculate the first part of the expression based on gearbox pitch
if (gearboxPitch == tpi) {
  numberPart1 = (math expression A);
}
else if (gearboxPitch == in_per_rev) {
  numberPart1 = (math expression B);
}
else if (gearboxPitch == mm) {
  numberPart1 = (math expression C);
}

// Calculate the rest based on leadscrew pitch
if (leadscrewPitch == tpi) {
  finalNumber = numberPart1 * (math expression D);
}
else if (leadscrewPitch == mm) {
  finalNumber = numberPart1 * (math expression E);
}
```

My question is: am I doing it the most efficient way right now? Or would it be a lot more efficient to have a single chain of conditionals to cover all possible cases, and do all the calculations in one shot (like below)? The way I've got it right now seems nice and readable, but don't want to sacrifice too much code readability for efficiency.

```
float finalNumber;

if (leadscrewPitch == tpi && gearboxPitch == tpi) {
  finalNumber = (do all the math in one go);
}
else if (leadscrewPitch == tpi && gearboxPitch == mm) {
  finalNumber = (do all the math in one go);
}
......and so on
```

Comment: A modern compiler and processor probably wouldn't care much.   An AVR with a...perhaps less modern compiler and more constrained register set might benefit from having all the math together.  Or not.  Definitely something as old as the 8051 you could change the generated code with some minor tweaking or ordering of seemingly unrelated parts.   Best thing to do is give it a shot.   You can fairly easily do this on godbolt.org

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a situation where one measurement unit needs to add or delete one enum, it only needs adding or deleting one 'if' statement for the current code, while the latter needs changing multiple statement.

Suppose another situation where (math expression A) needs modification, current code only needs one modification while the latter needs multiple modification based on how many enums the other measurement unit can be.

Thus, in my opinion, there is no need using a single chain.

One slight improvment is ordering enums by probability descending.